# problem with branding sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, branding

hi I put script editor in SharePoint 2013 and insert slider in it but with developer tools option I have 2 errors what should I do to solve this errors

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden) Home.aspx:962 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'href' of null
>       at _cUpdconetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic (Home.aspx:962)
>       at _cUpdonetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic (Home.aspx:962)
>       at eval (eval at ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames (init.js:1), :1:64)
>       at ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames (init.js:1)
>       at ProcessDefaultOnLoad (init.js:1)
>       at NotifyEventAndExecuteWaitingJobs (init.js:1)
>       at NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs (init.js:1)
>       at $_global_core (/_layouts/15/core.js?rev=LRiXwLWSJUxKuVCrXa3yDg%3D%3D:1)
>       at /_layouts/15/core.js?rev=LRiXwLWSJUxKuVCrXa3yDg%3D%3D:1

and the code I use in script editor is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery &amp; Bootstrap Carousel Demo</title>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="jquery-script-center">

<div class="jquery-script-ads"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
/* jQuery_demo */
google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/sports" style="width:100%" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 1</h1>
          <p>Aenean a rutrum nulla. Vestibulum a arcu at nisi tristique pretium.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/people" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Second    slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 2</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae egestas purus. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/abstract" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 3</h1>
          <p>Donec sit amet mi imperdiet mauris viverra accumsan ut at libero.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to apply your code on my side, and I advise you to do the following:

- There is a google AD script that unnecessary to use to show your slider. so I remove it in below final code.
- No need to use HTML and body tags in the `Script Editor`, the final code should look like:

**Code:**

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<div class="jquery-script-center">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/sports" style="width:100%" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 1</h1>
          <p>Aenean a rutrum nulla. Vestibulum a arcu at nisi tristique pretium.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/people" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Second    slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 2</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae egestas purus. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/abstract" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 3</h1>
          <p>Donec sit amet mi imperdiet mauris viverra accumsan ut at libero.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

**Output without error in console**

[image]

**Note:** Adding the above code in script editor is not a solution to show dynamic image in a slider, so you have two options to do that:

1. The first option: you should add the above code within repeater in Visual web part to read your image from asset library and show it as slider.
2. the second option: to create an Item style and use the above CSS and scripts to render data from your library

Comment: thank you very much is there any manual about your  solutions  ? I prefer first solution .

Comment: let me bring to you the  detail steps for the first option :)

Comment: This link is a ready solution with source code to can use slider web part with SP 2013 http://www.ashokraja.me/post/SharePoint-2013-Carousel-WebPart-with-Nivo-Slider.aspx hope it helps you :)

Comment: is there any step by step guide in net to do that?no different between first and second solution I just need a manual

Comment: what about no programming solutions? is there any way not to use visual studio and do it in sharepoint ?

Comment: There is no explicit guide to do that, so I provided the above link that explains the detail steps to use a ready solution that just requires to download solution,take the WSP file,then deploys it(no code requires if you don't need to change it)Regarding the 2 solution check the detail steps at https://en.share-gate.com/blog/image-slider-with-sharepoint-2013-search-results and http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/06/18/sharepoint-integrate-a-slider-with-the-content-query-web-part-part-1-what-does-my-slider-need-to-work-aspx/ please don't hesitate to inform me if you need more clarification

Comment: sorry but the code you correct for me  not show the slider in full width can you help me?

Comment: sure, you are welcome. let me go back to home and I will try it in my environment as soon as possible.

Comment: just change <div class="jquery-script-center"> this with <div class="jquery-script-center" style="width: 100% !important;"> and make your master page oslo.